# How to write copy statement using snowflake scripting?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying write the copy statement in snowflake scripting. My copy statement is working fine out side the stored procedure. when i put the copy statement inside stored procedure it is not working.
it is so weird. Please could anyone help me on this?

```
create or replace procedure sp_demo_load(sysdate varchar)
returns varchar not null
language sql
as
$$
begin
    copy into stg.tb_demo_input (name, id, address)
    from @stg.demo_stage/DEMO.20220427.psv.gz 
        file_format = (format_name = 'stg.demo_ff',
        error_on_column_count_mismatch = true, encoding = 'iso-8859-1') ;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Is there any error log you can share?

Comment: Without the error message as Felipe mentioned, it's hard to know for sure what the problem is. My suspicion is you may need to add `execute as caller` to your SP definition. That is a quick test and if it works I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @GregPavlik Weird this is there is no error just says null . When execute as caller it says null as well.  Thank you for helping guys

Comment: @FelipeHoffa There is no error. it is just saying NULL.  :(

Comment: Can you look at the logs of what was executed?

Comment: Copy executed with 0 files processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your copy statement "worked fine the first time" but if you run it again you will get 0 files loaded, because it has already loaded those file. This is because Snowflake is tracking which file have been loaded, thus there is no point to load them again.

Which means your SP is just fine.

To test truncate the destination table, and then run your SP, it should load the files, on the first run.